# How to display pictures random from a array of pictures on a website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I want to add a banner to my website, which displays a random picture of a specific picture pool, changing after a refresh. How can I search for such a documentation? I do not know for what key words I have to search for. Mainly searching for a solution with angular.
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You may want a carousel, but without any specifics, it's difficult to say, and it's not clear what specific issue/s you're having.

Comment: Having the issue that I do not know any key words I can search for. do not need a carousel which changes die pictures after a specified time period. I just want to place a banner on the website and when the page is refreshed the picture displayed in that banner is randomly selected from a pool (array) of pictures.

Comment: What is preventing you from doing this?

Comment: the implementation. I do not know how to search for it (any key words), since I did not find any useful documentation yet with my description.

Comment: You need to pick a random number from 0-(size of image array) and use that as the image URL.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide some more relevant code and typically in SO want to elaborate on what you've tried to do and how far it got you.  If I am understanding your question enough, you have a pre-existing array of urls and want to simply pick a random one each time a page is shown or a component is rendered.

```js
const images = ['https://picsum.photos/id/9/5000/3269', 'https://picsum.photos/id/11/2500/1667', 'https://picsum.photos/id/21/3008/2008'];

// pick a random item from the list
const rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*images.length);
const src = images[rand];

console.log(rand, src);

// just use the src value in your component, it will get a new one each time it is mounted or rendered
// or, build a DOM element if not in a framework
const img = document.createElement('IMG');
img.src = src;
img.style.width = "100vw";
document.body.appendChild(img);
```